# How to recover from an "umount -a -l"

Tags: linux, umount

So I did this silly thing:

```
umount -a -l
```

And had nothing in my `fstab` so couldn’t do `mount -a`

So I thought: “It will be ok when restart” … But no.

Now I'm stuck at launch and I don't have anything to logon just and error telling me to contact administrator

I'm using Kali Linux.

**EDIT:**

I can log by pressing `ctrl+alt+F2` (it opens a shell)

before I did this umount I did this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/sdb2
```

So apparently it was a bad idea

Now `df -h` says that / is full and I got both 'rootfs' and '/dev/disk/by-uuid/' mounted on / (and full).

But the strange thing is that `du -sch /` tells me `9.5G` and my disk capacity is `20Go`.

I also did the following things:

- Change my fstab and remove UUID lines by more 'usual' lines and reboot : did nothing at all.
- Ran `fsck.ext4 /dev/sda6` says 'clean'
- Ran `upgrade-grub` just in case

I don't know what to do anymore :|

Comment: Boot from livecd/usb and update fstab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Booting live, I mounted my partition /dev/sda6

```
mount /deV/sda6 /mnt/
```

then I saw with `du` a 9.0G file called */mnt/dev/sda*.

`head /mnt/dev/sda | cat -e` revealed that it was full of `^@` which is *null* in [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)

This file was the result of my fail.

In fact when I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/sdb2` I did something wrong (mistype,  `of=/dev/sda`, ...) and filled my disk with zeros

after removing this file everything was ok since disk was not full.